# Faking a Streaming Response in Django to Avoid Heroku Timeout

Tags: django, pdf, heroku

I have a Django app that uses [`django-wkhtmltopdf`](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf) to generate PDFs on Heroku. Some of the responses exceed the 30 second timeout. Because this is a proof-of-concept running on the free tier, I'd prefer not to tear apart what I have to move to a worker/ poll process. My current view looks like this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    do_custom_stuff()
    return super(MyViewClass, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way I can override the `dispatch` method of the view class to fake a streaming response [like this](http://www.rodvdka.co.za/heroku/long-polling/h12/h18/django/2016/10/13/long-polling-heroku.html) or with the Empy Chunking [approach mentioned here](https://www.jamesward.com/2015/06/02/redirecting-and-chunking-around-herokus-30-second-request-timeout) to send an empty response until the PDF is rendered? Sending an [empty byte will restart the timeout process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses) giving plenty of time to send the PDF.

Comment: How would faking the response solve the timeout problem?

Comment: @DanielRoseman good question, updated to explain.

Comment: Could you use channels to make a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I solved a similar problem using Celery, something like this.

```
def start_long_process_view(request, pk):
    task = do_long_processing_stuff.delay()
    return HttpResponse(f'{"task":"{task.id}"}')
```

Then you can have a second view that can check the task state.

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult

def check_long_process(request, task_id):
    result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    return HttpResponse(f'{"state":"{result.state}"')
```

Finally using javascript you can just fetch the status just after the task is being started. Updating every half second will more than enough to give your users a good feedback.

If you think Celery is to much, there are light alternatives that will work just great: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Comment: :) That's actually the approach I am trying to avoid if I can just because we are about out of budget. I will go with worker/ polling if needed though. Thanks.

Comment: Is logging to the browser's console considered a response?